# while connecting planetscale using strapi CMS got this Error

Tags: node.js, strapi, planetscale

planetscale details are Like below

`DATABASE_URL='mysql://username:************@host/strapi_db_name?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":true}'`

same value using to connect

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'mysql2',
    connection: {
      host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'server hostname'),
      database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'strapi_db_name'),
      user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'username'),
      password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'password'),
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: env('DATABASE_SSL', true)
      },
    },
  }
});
```

I got Error like:

```
 debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-02-23 11:34:08.104] error: Unknown dialect mysql2
Error: Unknown dialect mysql2
```

Comment: Just use the normal `mysql` but even that as mentioned on strapi forum and some threads, Strapi said that they won't drop the "foreign key constraints" so kind of hard to bypass it https://forum.strapi.io/t/has-anyone-used-planetscale-com/9875 but I've seen that somebody on reddit bypass it but without ease

Answer (score 1):

**`mysql2`** is not a valid option among Strapi's supported database clients, please see this section in the documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/database#connection-configuration-object

Comment: Np, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it does solve your problem :)

Comment: Update: mysql2 now shows in the Typescript quick start.